Apache poi no logra tomar excepción al instanciar XSSFWorkbook
Tengo un gran problema, cuando inicializo la clase org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.
try {   
   logger.error("inicia crearexcel");
               try {
                  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
               }
               catch (RuntimeException e){
                      logger.info("inicia crearexcel 1 error runtime" + e.getMessage(), e  )

}
               catch(Exception e ){
                  logger.info("inicia crearexcel 1 error " +e.getMessage(), e  );
               }
               finally{
                   logger.info("finally crear instabncia XSSFWorkbook " );
               }
               logger.error("inicia crearexcel 1");
.
.
.
.
.
}
        catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("inicia crearexcel - Exception --> " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }finally {
            logger.error("inicia crearexcel - Final -->");
            logger.info("inicia crearexcel - Final 222-->");
        } 

Y lo único que pinta en el log del servidor web, es
** logger.error("inicia crearexcel"); **
Y todo aquello que está en el bloque "finally"
Utilizo Maven para el tema de las librerías. En en pom.xml registre como dependencia poi-ooxml 5.2.4 así como sus dependencias según lo indicada en la página de apache-poi
Y debería también pinta en el log
**logger.error("inicia crearexcel 1");
** pero no lo hace lo cual me parece bien extraño ya que si está después de try/catch debería pintarlo pero no es asi
De alguna manera al momento de instanciar la clase hace que se produzca un error y el Exception no lo está tomando.
Cómo una prueba, inmediatamente después de
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
También agregué una línea de código para que pinte en el log, pero no lo hace, solo pinta lo del bloque finally, lo que me hace entender que se dispara una excepción pero por algún motivo el try/catch no logra tomarlo, necesito identificar que error es para dar solución y el proceso de generar un archivo Excel termine ok.
También revise en el log del servidor eeb y no hay más detalle sobre algún error al ejecutar ese código
